# How can I append data from one spreadsheet to another one?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have this handy script for about a year. Works really well to periodically save data (crypto prices) on multiple worksheets. But my spreadsheet is about to explode, too many cells. So I would like to use multiple spreadsheets. In order to do so I need to mix my script a little but I wasn't able to do it alone.

- Goal : **Append a range of values in a different Spreadsheet.**

> ```
>  // [START modifiable parameters]
> var rangeToLog = 'Source!A1:B20';
> var sheetToLogTo = 'Target';
> // [END modifiable parameters]
> ////////////////////////////////
>
> /**
> * Appends a range of values to the end of an archive sheet.
> * A timestamp is inserted in column A of each row on the archive sheet.
> * All values in rangeToLog go to one row on the archive sheet.
> *
> * @OnlyCurrentDoc
> */
> function appendValuesToArchiveSheet() {
>   // version 1.4, written by --Hyde, 30 January 2020
>   //  - use Array.prototype.some() to skip empty rows when concating
>   //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/27095918?msgid=27148911
>   // version 1.3, written by --Hyde, 26 January 2020
>   //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/26760916
>   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
>   var valuesToLog = ss.getRange(rangeToLog).getValues();
>   var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToLogTo);
>   if (!logSheet) {
>     logSheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetToLogTo);
>     logSheet.appendRow(['Date time', 'Data']);
>   }
>   var rowToAppend = [new Date()].concat(
>     valuesToLog.reduce(function concatArrays_(left, right) {
>       var arrayContainsData = right.some(function isNonBlanky_(element, index, array) {
>         return element !== null && element !== undefined && element !== '';
>       });
>       return arrayContainsData ? left.concat(right) : left;
>     })
>   );
>   logSheet.appendRow(rowToAppend);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

There are two ways to get the [spreadsheet](http://Spreadsheet) object of a different spreadsheet from the one bound to the script:

- [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)):

> Opens the spreadsheet with the given ID. A spreadsheet ID can be
> extracted from its URL. For example, the spreadsheet ID in the URL
> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit#gid=0 is
> "abc1234567".

- [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openByUrl(String)):

> Opens the spreadsheet with the given URL. Throws a scripting exception
> if the URL does not exist or the user does not have permission to
> access it.

You can pick whatever suits you the best, but there is no difference in performance. I prefer `openById` because you pass a "shorter" string (`id` vs `url`).

### Solution:

**Change:**

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var valuesToLog = ss.getRange(rangeToLog).getValues();
var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToLogTo);
```

**To:**

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // source spreadsheet
var ss_t = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id of target spreadsheet'); // target spreadsheet
var valuesToLog = ss.getRange(rangeToLog).getValues();
var logSheet = ss_t.getSheetByName(sheetToLogTo); // logSheet of the target spreadsheet
```

and `logSheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetToLogTo);` to `logSheet = ss_t.insertSheet(sheetToLogTo);`

**Full Code:**

```
// [START modifiable parameters]
var rangeToLog = 'Source!A1:B20';
var sheetToLogTo = 'Target';

function appendValuesToArchiveSheet() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // source spreadsheet
  var ss_t = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id of target spreadsheet'); // new code
  var valuesToLog = ss.getRange(rangeToLog).getValues();
  var logSheet = ss_t.getSheetByName(sheetToLogTo); // modified code
  if (!logSheet) {
    logSheet = ss_t.insertSheet(sheetToLogTo); // modified code
    logSheet.appendRow(['Date time', 'Data']);
  }
  var rowToAppend = [new Date()].concat(
    valuesToLog.reduce(function concatArrays_(left, right) {
      var arrayContainsData = right.some(function isNonBlanky_(element, index, array) {
        return element !== null && element !== undefined && element !== '';
      });
      return arrayContainsData ? left.concat(right) : left;
    })
  );
  logSheet.appendRow(rowToAppend);
}
```

Comment: I get this error with both of the solutions :

Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
appendValuesToArchiveSheet @ Code.gs:21

Comment: Supressed the @OnlyCurrentDoc
It works well now ! Thank you so much fro your help !